# How to change data in a mongoose document with the _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I know this may seem like a generic question but I have done research and it didn't seem to work. I'm making a discord bot and I'm new to this kind of thing. I keep getting this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Data.users index`

This is the code I used:
`user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: msg.author, gold: 5});`

What is the reason of this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

mongoose `.findOneAndUpdate()` expects 2 parameters:

- the `_id` of the document you'd update
- the new data of the document
  So, your code should be this way instead:

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: msg.author}, {gold: 5});
```

Comment: I tried but I still got the same error. Am i. meant to write _id before ```msg.author```

Comment: yes that's true. It needs to be a filter object. There, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) descibes very clearly what the parameters are:

[image]

- first parameter: filter
- second parameter: update
- third parameter: settings object

In our case, you pass a single object, which is interpreted as the filter. You need to pass two objects:

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({_id: msg.author}, {gold: 5});
```

This specifies that you want to update `gold` to `5` for the first record whose `_id` equals `msg.author`.

See more examples here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Note, that this answer assumes that you have an `_id` field. If it has a different name, then use that instead.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation but even when I put ur code in mine I got the same error. Does it have anything to do with the fact that ```gold``` is not the only thing in the document?

Comment: @biggestpenguinfan the error is complaining about index duplication. I wonder what primary key and unique keys you have on the users table.

Comment: sorry I haven't done this sort of thing before, what do you mean by keys?